# Reducing duplication of template parameters in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

This is not a major code breaking issue, I'm just wondering if I'm missing some neat trick.

If I am writing a templated class, I may start like this:

```cpp
// some_header.h
template <typename TypeParameter, size_t max_array_size>
class TemplatedClass
{
    std::array<TypeParameter, max_array_size> MyTemplatedArray;

public:
    TypeParameter do_something()
    {
        /* do something with TypeParameter and max_array_sizein here */
    }
}
```

This is fine, but when I have less trivial templated examples, I tend to separate out the function definitions from the declarations, like so:

```cpp
// some_header.h
template <typename TypeParameter, size_t max_array_size>
class TemplatedClass
{
    std::array<TypeParameter, max_array_size> MyTemplatedArray;

public:
    TypeParameter do_something();

    /*

    Many more function declarations

    */
}

template <typename TypeParameter, size_t max_array_size>
TemplatedClass<TypeParameter, max_array_size>::do_something()
{
    /* do something with TypeParameter and max_array_sizein here */
}

/*

Many more function definitions, all with:

template <typename TypeParameter, size_t max_array_size>
TemplatedClass<TypeParameter, max_array_size>

at the start

*/
```

The aim of this would be to have a classic skeleton class definition that can easily be read by others at a glance. I don't mind doing this, but the annoying thing is when I want to modify the template parameters. What is one change in the first example, ends up being `1 + 2 * n` changes in the second example!

So what I am wanting to know is: Is there a way to make the second example's template parameters more maintainable? Maybe something similar to a typedef/using or maybe some keyword I haven't heard of?

Comment: Just drop the split of declaration and implementation. Note that this split is needed since C++ has inherited headers from C, so code had to be placed in ccp file and declaration in header file. With templates everything is in header files (usually), there is no need for to keep things apart. Also C++20 finally has introduced modules which will remove need of header files, so no more having separate declaration and definition.

Comment: if `/*do soemthing*/` does not depend on the template parameters you should move those methods to a non-template base class. If `/*do something*/` does depend on the template parameters you need more than 2 changes anyhow. I don't think there is a nice answer to your question, but in practice it isnt an issue (also because when it matters you can still define the methods in the class directly)

Comment: Thanks @MarekR. I am aware I could just stick to example 1, but I thought that example 2 was a fairly common thing to do to make things more readable. Perhaps it's not as common as I imagined.

Comment: Yup, the idea was they did depend on the template parameters @463035818_is_not_a_number, and I've edited accordingly. I see your point about having to do multiple edits anyway, but I just feel it's something the compiler might have been able to work out, perhaps with an alias or something.

Comment: @Cascades It is common to separate declaration `(.h|.hpp)` and implementation (`.impl`) for methods of class templates. Your second example is valid.

Comment: I'm just saying that this practice was introduced to solve some problem which doesn't stand on your way. Now it is so imprinted in our minds (mine too) it is sometimes hard to get rid off when not needed.

Comment: You can use preprocessor definitions...

Comment: I hadn't thought of that @AlexGuteniev!! Both a great solution... and not ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a non-answer:

Suppose, `/*do something*/` depends on the template parameters. In that case, having to fix the signature is the smaller issue. You need to fix the implementation.

The other case is that `/*do something*/` does not depend on the template parameters. Then you can move the methods to a non template base class.

---

A more serious attempt to answer the question:

What if `TemplatedClass` would have only a single template parameter instead of many? Instead of using a bunch of template parameters for `TemplatedClass` you can use a single tag and definition of the actual parameters can be defered to traits:

```
#include <array>

template <typename Tag> struct value_type_impl;
template <typename Tag> using value_type = typename value_type_impl<Tag>::type;
template <typename Tag> constexpr int array_size = 123;

template <typename Tag>
class TemplatedClass {
    std::array<value_type<Tag>, array_size<Tag> > MyTemplatedArray;    
public:
    value_type<Tag> do_something();
};

template <typename Tag>
value_type<Tag> TemplatedClass<Tag>::do_something() {
    return {};
}

// the tag
struct foo_tag{};

// specializations for foo_tag:
template <> struct value_type_impl<foo_tag> { using type = int; };
template <> constexpr int array_size<foo_tag> = 123;


int main() {
    TemplatedClass<foo_tag> tc;
}
```

Now the burdon is on the user of the template to define one tag and then specialize the required traits for that tag. Though, the method definition has only a single template parameter that does not need to change when more "parameters" (traits) are added or removed. Of course you still need to fix the implementation.

If you were looking merely for some syntactic sugar, I am not aware of something that would help without changing the template itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It certainly seems to be a solution, even if it's not the "neat trick" I was hoping for. I'll give it a day or two, and then most probably mark this as a solution if nothing else comes up!

Comment: @Cascades tbh i consider the first part of this answer or Mareks comment ("just don't do it") the right answer, I just felt that this would be a little too slim for an answer, hence I tried to find something that does what you ask for: convenient definition of the methods seperate from the class that avoids to change the parameters when they change.

Comment: Yup, I understand that! I won't use the code you wrote, and will just deal with things as they are! Thanks a lot!